# What could this water leak be under my car?

Tags: mazda, leak, mazda-3

I noticed a coolant leak coming out under my Mazda 3 2007. It is right in the center next to what looks like an overflow outlet.

I have noticed a hole which looks like this, and coolant comes from it.

What can the cause be?

Comment: Could you be specific - I think you missed a word "...next to my ... I notic..."

Comment: happens to my car all the time... It means your AC is working well :-) dont worry

Comment: What makes you think it is coolant? Try catching some in a container - is it clear or green or orange?

Answer (score 15):

What you are more than likely seeing is condensation from your A/C unit. The drain for these are *usually* located on the passenger side of the car about where the firewall is at (just behind the engine). This is ***completely normal***.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose this I would back up your car and touch and smell the liquid.  Antifreeze is usually green and slimy and shines in sun light.  Water from condensation is usually colder if it just leaked out and well its water haha.
Fuel, smells like fuel and stains and concrete with a dark discoloration turning blackish in the sun and smells like gas/ diesel.  when fresh, gas usually has a slight blue coloring to it and smells strong.